# How to place foreground images at specified locations over background image in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, foreground

I am working on a task in which I have some objects like humans and toys and food which are foreground images/objects and I have a background image, for eg. like a park. I need to place foreground images/objects at specified locations over background image. I am using Matlab.

I was able to place a foreground image over background image, but its positioned in the center - not at a specified position. 
How can I place foreground images at specified locations over background image using Matlab ?

My code is as follows:

```
figure1 = figure;

ax1 = axes('Parent',figure1);
ax2 = axes('Parent',figure1);

set(ax1,'Visible','off');
set(ax2,'Visible','off');

[a,map,alpha] = imread('foreground.png');
I = imshow(a,'Parent',ax2);

set(I,'AlphaData',alpha);
imshow('Background.jpg','Parent',ax1);
```

My images:

1) What I want:

[image]

2) What I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: You could try using `image()` instead of `imshow()`. It lets you specify the coordinates of the pixels: `image(x,y,img)`. That combined with the `hold` command should be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution using [ginput](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) in which the user clicks on a figure (here only once) and you fetch the coordinates of the point(s). In this example, there is a message box asking the user to select a point, then the foreground image is drawn over the background image. Notice that in my example I replace the pixels from the background image with those of the foreground. i.e. I do not use alpha and transparency. Hope that's fine for you; if not please tell me.

In the example, my 'background' image is the peppers image that ships with Matlab and the 'foreground' image is the pears image that also ships with Matlab. I use a small portion of the image for the demonstration.

Here is the code:

```
clear
clc
close all
%// Set up background image (peppers.png) and foreground image (part of
%// pears.png)
BackgroundImage = imread('peppers.png');

DummyForeground = imread('pears.png');
ForegroundImage = DummyForeground(50:200,50:200,:);

%// Get size of foreground image
[rowFore,colFore,channelFore] = size(ForegroundImage);

figure

imshow(BackgroundImage);

hMsg = msgbox('Select an anchor point for foreground image','modal');
uiwait(hMsg)
```

This looks like this:

[image]

```
%// Use ginput to prompt user to select a single point (i.e. the 1 in
%// brackets).
[x,y] = ginput(1);
```

Calling `ginput` results in the following:

[image]

```
 x = round(x);
 y = round(y);

%// Important!
hold on

%// Replace pixels of background image with foreground image. 
BackgroundImage(y:y+rowFore-1,x:x+colFore-1,:) = ForegroundImage;

imshow(BackgroundImage);
```

And finally the background image with the foreground image:

[image]

Note: It looks like there is a shift between the cursor and the actual image placed; that happened when I took the screenshot haha it's not a bug :)

Now if you would like to add many images in the foreground, you could easily modify the code using multiple points for ginput, calling it like so:

```
[x,y] = ginput %// Indefinite # of points)

or [x,y] = ginput(SomeNumber) %// Any number you want
```

and add appropriate images for every point you selected.

Hope that was clear enough and it gets you started!

Comment: I tried your code, but I m getting black region around foreground objects. Can that be removed ? Thanks!

Comment: Yes I guess! Does your original foreground image contain that border? You can look at imclearborder maybe? Otherwise please post your images that will be easier to fix. Thanks!

Comment: I can't post images due to less reputation. But links are: result I want: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqm48tov9x55qny/Scene0_0.png?dl=0). Result I m getting: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmoxa1mk481pd0s/erroneous_result.jpg?dl=0). Do you have any idea on how to remove black region around bear ? Thanks!

Comment: I'll link your images in your question. Do you want the image of the bear to be place in the image with the kids?

Comment: Kids, bear, toys and other objects are foreground objects. When I place objects, I get black region (opaque) around the objects (kids, bear, toys, etc). I need to remove that black region around the object (in this case, bear). Thanks for linking images!